# how to refresh div via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Currently i am developing a web site using rails 3.0.3.

I have a model called **events**.
In my **events_controller.rb** file i have code like this:

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  #redirect_to events_url
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to (events_url), :notice => 'Event deleted' }
    format.js
  end
end
```

---

i have one **index.html.haml** file there i have written this:

```
- content_for :title do
  Listing Events

%div#event
  = render :partial => "task"
```

---

I have one **partial** file called **_task.html.haml**
where i have assigned div id and for ajax remote true: like this-

```
- @events.each do |event|
  %ol.hoverbox
    %li.all{:id =>"event_#{event.id}"}
      = link_to image_tag(event.photo.url), event_path(event)
      .abc
        = event.name
        %br/
      .bca
        = event.start_date
        = event.start_time
        = link_to 'Delete', event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                   :method => :delete,
                                   :remote => :true
```

---

and finally i have my  **destroy.js.haml** where i have written -

```
$('##{dom_id(@event)}').remove();
```

---

It is successfully deleting with ajax but counter is showing the same value and after manually refreshing the page the counter is decreasing.
please tell how to update via ajax.

and in my model that is **event.rb** file i am counting the no of events like this for maintaining the counter:

```
   def current_date
        Date.today
    end

    def self.find_current
        Event.find :all, :conditions => ['(start_date  = current_date)'], :order => 'start_date '
    end

    def self.count_past(current_date = Date.today)
       Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date < ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
    end

    def self.count_upcoming(current_date = Date.today)
       Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date > ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
   end

    def self.count_today(current_date = Date.today)
        Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date = ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
    end
```

---

i have one more partial that is in layouts called **subnav.html.haml** heer i am showing the count on web page

```
      %li
        - if params[:controller] == "brands"
          // my code
        - elsif params[:controller] == "events"
          %a.blue.tt-top-center{:title => "Today's Events", :href => events_path(:view => "today") }#{Event.count_today}
          %span Today's Events

  %li
    - if params[:controller] == "brands"
 //my code
    - elsif params[:controller] == "events"
      /= link_to "Upcomming events", events_path(:view => "upcoming") 
      %a.tt-top-center{:title => "upcomming Events", :href => events_path(:view => "upcoming") }#{Event.count_upcoming}
      %span Upcoming Events
```

i searched through many links but not getting the way to update my count, please help me and make me understand in elaborative way because on web sites they are giving hints which is not matching with my criteria, so please help me and use the same name of class and url what i have used in my code, I would be really thankful to u for your help.

Answer (score 0):

put `$('##{dom_id(@event)}').reset();` in `destroy.js.erb` file.